# Deadlock question 19.5 in elements of programming interviews

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

This question from elements of programming interviews claims there is a deadlock in the following code in the scenario where "U1 initiates a transfer to U2 and immediately afterwards U2 initiates a transfer to U1. Since each transfer takes place in a separate thread its possible for the first thread to lock U1 and then the second to lock U2"

```
class Account:
    _global_id = 0

    def __init__(self, balance):
        self._balance = balance
        self._id = Account._global_id
        Account._global_id += 1
        self._lock = threading.RLock()

    def get_balance(self):
        return self._balance

    @staticmethod
    def transfer(acc_from, acc_to, amount):
        th = threading.Thread(target=acc_from._move, args=(acc_to, amount))
        th.start()

    def _move(self, acc_to, amount):
        with self._lock:
            if amount > self._balance:
                return False
            acc_to._balance += amount
            self._balance -= amount
            print('returning True')
            return True
```

I do not see how there is a deadlock in that case. U1 and U2 have separate locks and as far as I can tell, thread1 just locks U1 and thread2 locks U2 since the _move method just uses self._lock and doesn't touch acc_to._lock. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the right example? I don't know that book, but I've seen books like it where there will be multiple examples for one problem. E.g., "...example A doesn't deadlock, but it also doesn't..., so we try to fix it by adding another lock as in example B, now it ..., but now it can deadlock."

Comment: A typical deadlock in this kind of examples occurs when two threads are trying to get same two locks but in different order. But this is clearly NOT that case.

Comment: I was confused by this as well. I think the deadlock scenario would only make sense if `acc_to._balance += amount` was guarded by a `with acc_to._lock` statement, but I'd be curious if we're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt and did not find a known error on the [book's website](https://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/). Based on the explanation of deadlock in the section before this problem, I think it should be

```
def _move(self, acc_to, amount):
        with self._lock, acc_to._lock:
```

instead of

```
def _move(self, acc_to, amount):
        with self._lock:
```

since that's the primary way deadlock will occur.